# iphone quizz app

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm thinking about creating an iPhone quiz application. I want to use a grouped table view where the header is the question and the cells the answers. But I would need to reuse the same table View for all the questions? What is the best practice for this? Can I create a segue from a table view controller to itself? If i store a variable in the controller will I be able to decrement it if the user taps "back" (the table view will be in a navigation controller). Or better yet remember all answers so the user can go back and forward and only modify a few previous answers before taping "test done"...

Comment: Simple advise: Just start! You will get your answers while you are developing. And on the plus side, you will learn a lot more than when we tell you what we would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with dasdom but just to give you some direction:
For this kind of App, i have two suggestion to make. One is you should use the concepts of multiple views single view controller, that would be easy.
But if you want to give the functionality of going back and forth, the best thing i can think of is Paging. Include paging in your app and you can go to any question just by a swipe.
As far as reusing is concerned just create that table view in a different class and use it as a superclass in the view controller and update the data source and reload the table View.